# Web api Angular issue with data that is returning

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api2

I am having my controller as follows

```
 public IQueryable<Customer> GetCustomers()
    {
        return db.Customers;
    }
```

I am calling this from angular js as follows

```
angular.module('crudModule').controller('CustomerController', function ($scope, 

$http, crudService) {

    var data = crudService.Customers();

    data.then(function successCallback(response) {
        debugger;
        $scope.Customers = JSON.stringify(response.data);
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        alert('Invalid response');
    });
});
```

I am able to see the data at postion `0` but not on position `1` can some one tell me what was the issue

[image]

[image]

My console displays as follows
[image]

Comment: If you try console.log(response.data) in your navigator what's display ? I think's debug javascript in visual studio is not realy good. Try to debug with chrome. I never use vs debug for my javascript.

Comment: added the image that I am getting when I write it to console

Comment: Strange, try to return db.Customer.ToList() from your controller .NET.

Comment: still the same issue

Comment: I believe it is not able to serialize the customer object for its nested virtual reference to other objects , try creating a copy of Customer object only with the properties init and try send it to your UI as ToList(). see whether this fix the issue or not

Comment: I changed this way and it is working now `// GET: api/Employees
        public IHttpActionResult GetCustomers()
        {
            var result = db.Customers.Select(e => new { e.Address, e.City, e.ContactName, e.CompanyName, e.CustomerID }).ToList();
            return Ok(result);
        }`